# ArcGIS Web App Builder On Edit Complete

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I am using the Edit Widget and the Batch Attribute Editor widget to edit our Feature Layer with a Web App Builder.     I would like to be able to modify two attributes automatically when the Edit is Complete with these widgets without the user having to enter the attributes.    I would like to update a date field and a user field.    I know this can be done via the Editor Tracking Fields,  but the layer is edited in ArcMap and I only want to update the attributes when an edit occurs via WAB.     Is there a place in WAB where I can put some custom code to set these attributes when an edit is compete?   Do I need to create a widget that listens for the on edit complete?

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the-box function for this. Unfortunately, you would need to write an own widget for that (or incorporate a button "Save" into a current widget or place it somewhere else in the app layout). The function would send a POST to the Feature Service resource ([UpdateFeatures](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Update_Features/02r3000000zt000000/)) specifying the current time and logged-in user. It should be clicked after each edit operation.

Otherwise, you could also listen for the edit operation occurring and execute it behind the scene every time some update occurs (a bit harder, but doable).

It's going to be a lot of JavaScript.